# populate user data in list form

Tags: javascript

I have a list with fields name "User name", "Telephone" and "Department", i want that when user click on add new item and open new form. These 3 fields should get auto populate with logged in user details. I do not want to go with infopath template. Can someone provide me javascript for the same. Thanks

Comment: Which version are you using? SP 2013 or SP2010?

Comment: I am using SP2010